# How to protect credential in AWS when connecting to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, key, credentials

Sorry if this question is too simple. I started learning AWS not long ago:

As far as I know, AWS allows to create IAM role and grant needed permission, for example, to access S3 bucket.

If I need to access an S3 bucket to retrieve needed data, I can probably use ssh/winscp to do it.

Question is what about if I need to create a connection in a program? how do I protect the key and key secret from showing as plain text in a program? What is the best practice of doing that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: "I can probably use ssh/winscp to do it" --- you cannot, s3 uses its own protocol incompatible with ssh/scp.

Comment: "how do I protect the key and key secret from showing as plain text in a program?" --- in what program? It is application-specific on how the app loads and secures the credentials.

Comment: If your script in EC2 or lambda... You first create IAM Role, then assign role to its, so you can protect you credential (no need plain text in a program). If your script run out side AWS, credential as plain text in a program is needed.

Comment: @zerkms You can store in env, but still in local machine and not frequently change it, then I think almost equal to plain text

Comment: @TuanVA oh, I misread your original comment, my apologies.

Comment: @zerkms WinSCP [supports S3 protocol](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/s3).

Comment: @mdivk You didn't tell us anything about the *"program"*. – Though did you read WinSCP article [Protecting credentials used for automation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_protecting_credentials_for_automation)?

Answer (score 3):

> Question is what about if I need to create a connection in a program?
>   how do I protect the key and key secret from showing as plain text in
>   a program? What is the best practice of doing that?

It depends on where your program will be executing.

If your program is running within the AWS environment such as EC2 instance or as Lambda then you can make use of the recommended IAM Roles. IAM roles provides AWS service to service access. Here is the official documentation to learn more :

> We designed IAM roles so that your applications can securely make API
>   requests from your instances, without requiring you to manage the
>   security credentials that the applications use. Instead of creating
>   and distributing your AWS credentials, you can delegate permission to
>   make API requests using IAM roles.

[IAM Roles for Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)

Similarly, AWS Lambda has the concept of execution roles. A role assigned to the lambda removes the need of using credentials in the code to access another AWS service.

> A Lambda function also has a policy, called an execution role, that
>   grants it permission to access AWS services and resources.

[AWS Lambda Permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-permissions.html)

If your program is not going to be executed within the AWS environment then you can use AWS SDK to program to access an AWS service. For example the Node SDK will look for credentials in the following manner:

1. Credentials that are explicitly set through the service-client constructor
2. Environment variables
3. The shared credentials file

You are surely trying to avoid the first one so you can pass the credential as one of the other methods.

[Setting Credentials in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html)

[Working with AWS Credentials : Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html)